# Neo4j database maxing CPU following upgrade to 3.0

Tags: neo4j

I upgraded to Community version 3.0 and now when I open my database the CPU stays consistently above 85%. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, deleting the old installs and their config files and reinstalling, and letting it run in case neo4j was reindexing or similar and just needed time. The database was running very well under 3.0.0-M02 but I don't have that exe to try reinstalling that. I've tried 3.0.0-M05 which didn't help.

Can anyone suggest a way for me to get the database running properly again?

Answer (score 0):

Is it doing recovery? If you start the database, does it fully start as expected and then go into this "mode"? Can you do a thread dump and paste here? For capturing a thread dump use `jps -lm` to figure out which process ID your neo4j process has and capture the thread dump using `jstack <pid>`, e.g. `jstack 15432 > myfile.txt`